# Tomcat 7 RemoteHostValve not working for localhost

Tags: server, tomcat7, server.xml

I am trying to restrict access to a Tomcat 7 Server by using this valve: org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve.

It's working fine for other hosts, but I can not access the server locally by using the localhost (http://localhost:8080).

Here is the Valve:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve" allow="host2.xy.i|host2.xy.i|localhost"/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

for this function Hostname Lookups are needet.
Did you check that you have set ?

```
<Connector enableLookups="true" />
```

If its not working with the Hostname, you could reach the same result with:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
    allow="127\..*"/>
```

But check if you have localhost V6 IP, this example matches only ipv4

Comment: Hi and thanks four your answer. I have enableLookups set to true. As far as I understand, when using the RemoteAddrValve you can not use the RemoteHostValve at the same time. But I want to resolve the hosts by name. Right now I am using RemoteAddrValve and it works as long as the ips do not change. But if somebody connect via WiFi we got a problem.

Comment: If you are right that AddrValve and HostValve are conflictting, this would be a answer for my problem.
I yust know in apache it is possible to have Hosts and Addr in the same config.

Comment: @Radon8472
using RemoteHostValue i want to allow only http://localhost:8080/example. I mean to only localhost. so what should i write?

Comment: hmm, this `allow` attribute is only to restrict by RemoteAddr. I think you need addition an directory protection.
E.g. you define for DocumentRoot `deny all`, and then you define for folder /example `allow from localhost`.

Unfurtunally I know how to do this in apache httpd, but currently i dont know the equivalent for tomcat.

Maybe you find the informations behind this link: http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/118yzzccjs/deny-access-to-directory